# flutter : using google_mobile_ads is so slow inside list view and lagging the app scrolling

Tags: flutter, listview, ads

i tried google mobile ads  and native admob flutter  and both of them native ads are lagging the list view , is it like flutter isn't good enough or what ?

i tried the plugins SDK examples and implemented same as the tutorials they provided and no results ,
please help

Answer (score 0):

does the banner display like blinking? if so, you have to change your google_mobile_ads plugin in pubspec.yaml to be like this :

```
google_mobile_ads:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/SuaMusica/googleads-mobile-flutter.git
      path: packages/google_mobile_ads
      ref: feature/suamusica
```